# How can I split a CSV file linewise, retaining headers in both output files?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, csv

I am trying to split a csv file - sample.csv by following command.

```
split -n 2 -a 1 -d sample.csv test_
```

I get two files equal size one with header and other without header and lines trimmed off at the end.

when I se below script, The result displays on terminal but no file generated.

```
split -n 1/2 -a 1 -d sample.csv test_
```

Comment: You probably want to use something like [the csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of plain bash commands. CSV format is simple but not trivial (e.g. a CSV row can contain multiple lines, a CSV value can contain the separator if quoted, escaping quotes etc). Using a toolkit that is aware of proper CSV syntax will be easier and more robust.

Comment: @GACy20 I've been looking at this and there isn't a csvkit command that does this for you. However, one could probably cook something up using `csvjson` or `csvpy`, or go the long way around with `csvsql`.

Comment: I think I would use AWK, not `split`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like both commands are working as they are designed.

The first splits on bytes, which won't respect lines — useful when you are splitting, say, a large binary object, not so much when it's something like a CSV.

The second looks like a misreading of the documentation (but is still technically valid).

I think you meant to do this:

```
split -n l/2 -a 1 -d sample.csv test_
```

Note that is `lower case L slash two` not `one slash two` as you appear to have done.

You won't see the header row on the second part, because `split` is not really content aware.

One approach would be to do something like this

```
# extract header row and save
head -n1 sample.csv > header
# skip header row and split records to temporary files
tail -n+2 sample.csv | split -n l/2 -a 1 -d temp_
# make final files from header and split records
for f in temp_? ; do
  cat header "$f" > "${f/temp/test}"
  # clean up temporary file
  rm "$f"
done
# clean up header file
rm header
```

Comment: Do I run all these commands in a script file. when i run individual commands , for tail +2 i get tail : cannot open '+2' no such file or directory it prints only 10 lines not complete file

Comment: I got it worked after giving tail -n +2 sample.csv. after done script exits before executing rm header. do i place it before done

Comment: Since you're using text processing tools, you have to make the explicit assumption that records are line-delimited, i.e., that no field contains embedded newlines. If there are embedded newlines, you run the risk of corrupting the data by spitting inside records.

Comment: @kumar  You use `header` in every iteration, so you cannot delete the file inside the loop. There is no reason for the script to exit at that point. Maybe run with `-x` enabled in the script, and watch the debug.

Comment: got it. how do i append.csv to all split files

Comment: Either with the `--additional-suffix` param, or change the `cat` like so `cat header "$f" > "${f/temp/test}.csv"`

Comment: yup that works i can generate files like test_0.csv, test_1.csv. anyway we can start the file with test_1.csv instead of test_0.csv

Answer (score 3):

You can use the great [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/).

If you want to split in 2 files this input file

```
Column_1,Column_2,Column_3
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
J,K,L
M,N,O
P,Q,R
S,T,U
V,W,X
Y,Z,
```

you can use the [split verb](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/index.html#split)

```
mlr --csv split -m 2 input.csv
```

you will have

```
Column_1,Column_2,Column_3
A,B,C
G,H,I
M,N,O
S,T,U
Y,Z,
```

```
Column_1,Column_2,Column_3
D,E,F
J,K,L
P,Q,R
V,W,X
```

Comment: Note that this requires release 6.1.0 or later of Miller.

Answer (score 1):

Either you'll need to use multiple commands or you'll need something a bit heavier, like `awk`:

```bash
$ cat in.csv
Column_1,Column_2,Column_3
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
J,K,L
M,N,O
P,Q,R
S,T,U
V,W,X
Y,Z,""

$ awk '
    BEGIN { x='"$(awk 'END { print NR }' in.csv)"' / 2 }
    NR==1 { print > "out1.csv"; print > "out2.csv"; next }
    NR<=x { print > "out1.csv"; next }
          { print > "out2.csv" }
' in.csv

$ cat out1.csv
Column_1,Column_2,Column_3
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
J,K,L

$ cat out2.csv
Column_1,Column_2,Column_3
M,N,O
P,Q,R
S,T,U
V,W,X
Y,Z,""
```